# Using where() node to filter empty tags in Kapacitor

Tags: kapacitor

Using Kapacitor 1.3 and I am trying to use the following **where** node to keep measurements with an empty tag. Nothing is passing through and I get the same result with ==''.

```
| where(lambda: 'process-cpu__process-name' =~ /^$/)
```

I can workaround this issue using a default value for missing tags and filter on this default tag, in the following node but I am wondering if there is a better way structure the initial where statement and avoid an extra node.

```
| default()
  .tag('process-cpu__process-name','system')
| where(lambda: \"process-cpu__process-name\" == 'system' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure it doesn't pass, 'cause this

```
'process-cpu__process-name'
```

is a string literal it TICKScript, **not** a reference to a field, which is

```
"process-cpu__process-name"
```

You obviously got the condition always false in this case.

Quite common mistake though, especially for someone with previous experience with the languages that tolerates both single & double quote for mere string. :-)

Also, there's a function in TICKScript lambda called `strLength()`, find the doc [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.4//tick/expr/), please.